# Can't submit apps to AppStore: ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

> ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain.

New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.`" ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain`. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds."

I found this error during upload IPA to account.

Comment: So… what versions of Xcode and macOS did you use to build the app?

Answer (score 161):

If you're looking at this in November 2019, there's an obscure error in Xcode 11.2, which prevents uploading from that version to the App Store. You'll have to upgrade to Xcode 11.2.1, which is currently not available on the Mac App Store yet, but must be downloaded from the Developer Portal here: https://developer.apple.com/download/

The Xcode 11.2 Archive error log even states:

[image]

**Edit:**

Xcode 11.2.1 is now available on the AppStore:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Comment: Hello from November 2019!  Your diligence at adding this answer saved me probably hours of searching!  Thankyou!

Comment: Lol... trying this now too I hope it helps! already 8 upvotes! these were some busy 4 hours :D

Comment: Note that this may be related to the issue with building iOS apps with Xcode 11.2, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657087).

Comment: I tried all the other options here that didn't include updating to a beta version of Xcode but they didn't work. This worked for me running a React Native project with fastlane to building. Thank you.

Comment: why Apple doesn't release 11.2.1 in App Store? why Apple?!

Comment: For those who are looking **Xcode_11.2.1_GM_seed** is under **Beta** not Release. So developer.apple > Downloads > Applications > Beta > Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: If your using fast lane for your uploads, don't forget to change your command line tools setting: Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools: select 11.2.1

Comment: @LanceSamaria you are right but it seems to workaround the ITMS-90534 issue...

Comment: @Żabojad I think you misunderstood my comment. This answer does work and I upvoted it but when I first went to the developer portal I kept looking for 11.2.1 under Release. It took me about 20 minutes to release it was under Beta. I added the comment so the next person who comes along will go straight to beta instead of scratching their head. The answer doesn’t say “it’s under beta”

Comment: Xcode 11.2.1 is now released and available on AppStore

Comment: This is still working. Took a long time to download due to the Stay at Home. But the submission went smoothly after. Thanks again!

Comment: I am on Xcode 12.2 beta 3 and getting this error...

Answer (score 41):

I was having the same issue with Xcode 8.3 public version. I reinstall the Xcode and check it, but didn't work ...

Finally I found the issue , I have mistakenly selected Xcode 3.2-compatible in project format under project document. I changed it to Xcode 8.0-compatible and build & archived it. I could upload it without any errors. Check the screen shot attached ..

[image]

Comment: After reading a dozen other solutions, this allowed an app to be verified.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on an Xcode 10.1 project. Thanks!

Comment: So I should choose the latest option?

Comment: Error still exists either I choose Xcode 8.0-compatible, I am using Xcode 11 GM version

Comment: @besil, I also have Xcode 11.2 but I still have the error after selecting Xcode 11.0-compatible. Which option did you choose for the "Project format" ?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was wrong. I'm still having the problem. I think it's because I have downloaded Xcode from App Store, which is Xcode 11.2, while Apple release (as beta) Xcode 11.2.1

Comment: I am having the same issue in Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52). Could anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: If it's blocking, you should try download the Xcode Beta 11.2.1 and try to build and distribute your app. Or wait for new App Store updates

Comment: This is still valid in 2023. Click on the app folder on the left, you should see the general settings in the center, and open the file inspector in the right bar. Look for "Project format". Mine had changed to XCode 8 for some reason.

Answer (score 14):

## Xcode 11.2 is deprecated by Apple on November 5, 2019

---

## Always working workaround (Manual download)

[**Download the xip file from here**](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1/Xcode_11.2.1.xip)

Also:

> > ## [Latest Release version](https://developer.apple.com/download/release/) (Xcode 11.2.1)
>
> or
>
> > #### [Latest Beta version](https://developer.apple.com/download/) (Xcode 11.3 Beta)
>
> or
>
> > #### [Any version you need](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). And all other downloadable contents

Then extract and move it where you like.

You can find [all workaround histry of the issue here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660634/5623035)

Comment: Although this is the source of almost any current issues we are see from Apple's chaos, Ok @rmaddy

Comment: And there are already questions specific to that issue which you have already posted this exact same answer on. Posting this answer on questions that have nothing to do with Xcode 11.2 being deprecated isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

> The same issue occurs with me today (`13 July 2017`).
>
> As I was using `XCode 9 beta 2`, till date. Everything was working fine.
>
> The last build which I uploaded was on `9th of July 2017`, using `XCode 9 beta 2`.

**After trying a lot of changes, finally the fix was:**

**Upgrading to the latest beta** of `XCode`, which was `XCode 9 beta 3` (released on `10th July 2017`).

**BOTTOMLINE:**

If you are using any `beta` version of `XCode`, and if it is **outdated**. Apple will reject your build from that version causing the error asked by questioner. As long as the version is stable you don't need to worry.

It is recommended to check your current version is latest or not. If not, then download the latest XCode and push a new build achieved using the latest XCode beta

**Why I didn't use a stable version of XCode instead?**

The stable version at this time is `XCode 8.3.3`, and the language used is `Swift 3`.

Though there is minimum code breaking change from `Swift 3 to 4`, but my latest code base was `Swift 4`. Plus, you might be having `Pods` in your project which also has to be downgraded to the latest stable version. Until a stable version of XCode 9 is out. So, I opt to download the latest version of `XCode beta`

Comment: Reason to using xCode 9 beta: it is almost impossible to develop with Swift in xCode 8 and earlier. Because tons of bugs with autocomplete and highlighting eventually turning it into Notepad. So i VERY understand you :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: For anyone who is facing this issue in Xcode 12 Beta 4. Just install Xcode 12 Beta 6. It will be solved!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue today with the App Store version of Xcode 9.2.

It's definitely not a beta release, I'm guessing there's some delay between when the software is released and iTunes connect gets updated to expect the new version.

I've tried all the suggestions above, and none worked... but here's what (although pretty sketchy) did for work me:

- in organizer, right-click your archive and show in finder
- show package contents
- find Products/Applications/yourApp.app
- show package contents
- edit Info.plist
- change the value for DTXcodeBuild to a previous version (9.2 is 9C40b, 9.1 is 9C40)
- save and try again

This worked for me...

Comment: While this did work to get my binary uploaded to the store, and even let me test via test flight, I'm not able to submit for store review.  I get a different error when I try:

Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in MyApp.app/MyApp is 11.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.1.

Comment: Thanks for this - I followed your instructions and, while the build does make it as far as iTunesConnect (and TestFlight), I get an email warning me that it was built with an old version.

As the beta value in DTXcodeBuild is written by XCode itself, doesn't this mean we need a new XCode version with the fix in it rather than a fix at the store end? Or does the b at the end of the string not actually mean beta?

Comment: I’m not sure to be honest. In the Apple developer forums the general consensus was that it was just a matter of time before they’ll start accepting builds form 9.2. The b is odd, the hex digits are capitalized so the b isn’t a hex digit. Maybe it does mean beta and was left in by mistake?  I eventually bit the bullet downloaded 9.1 again and resubmitted a binary built with it.

Comment: Seems it's all working again now without an XCode update. So I guess 9C40b is the right version number, it was just Apple being a bit slow to update iTunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks! I just managed to submit the app for review. i had a problem with build version 11B52, and i change it to the previous version 11A1027.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying with Xcode 11, check the Xcode version. If it's **Version 11.0 (11A419c)** you cannot submit a build to the app store with this version. Get Xcode **Version 11.0 (11A420a)**.

Apps built with Xcode 11 GM seed (11A419c) can no longer be uploaded to App Store Connect. You can now submit apps built with Xcode 11 GM seed 2 (11A420a) using the iOS 13 SDK and watchOS 6 SDK to the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

> An error message it self says, Use stable (not beta) version of Xcode
>   to create a build.
>   Your mac OS should also be stable (not beta)

Use latest stable version of Xcode Tool [(Xcode 9)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) to create your build and upload using Application Uploader.

Ensure following points, while creating your build:

- Xcode version (Latest stable version of Xcode Tool - Current Xcode 9)
- Mac OS version (Latest stable MacOS version - High Sierra 10.12.7)
- Xcode Project (Document) Format version (Xcode 8.0-compatible)

Answer (score 2):

Right-Click on the archive file (.xcarchive) > Show Package Contents > Products > Applications > Right-Click on the app file > Show Package Contents > Double-Click on Info.plist to edit it

Remove *b* from the end of the value for **DTXcodeBuild** (for example change from 9C40b to 9C40)

Re-submit and it will work

Answer (score 2):

A new beta or Golden Master version of Xcode is about to be released, just look for it a few hours later.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this to resolve this issue:

1. Quit Xcode and any Simulators if they are opened.
2. Go to this link to download Xcode 11.2.1 GM seed under Applications. Its about 7GB: https://developer.apple.com/download/

[image]

3. After downloading, click the `Xcode_11.2.1_GM_Seed.xip` file to extract the Archive.
4. After extracting, move the Xcode file from `Downloads` to the Application folder.

[image]

5. Replace existing Xcode application.

[image]

6. Enter login password when prompted.

[image]

7. Wait for the Moving to complete.

[image]

8. When finished, launch Xcode and checkout `About Xcode` to confirm the latest version.

[image]

9. Build your App, increment your build number and submit to App Store.

[image]

**UPDATE:** Version 11.2.1 is now available from App Store itself since Nov 13.

Answer (score 1):

Archive you application using the stable Xcode version and upload it using Xcode beta. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Archive the application using the stable Xcode version and upload it using the same stable Xcode version. Xcode beta not required. This too solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing was updated Xcode 8.3.3, OS Serra 10.12.6 but I was still getting the issue. what I did and the issue got resolved is:

Open app store
searched xcode
Open Xcode from app store
it prompted me to install some missing features.
I followed the instructions and completed the wizard
Re-open Xcode and Archived my app and then started uploaded and it went successfully.

Hope it may help someone.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this issue by downloading XCode 8.2.1 from the App Store.

Re-archiving the project and submitting as usual.

Answer (score 0):

**For XCode 9.2**
Problem mostly in Command Line Tools version.

Best solution:

1. Reinstall XCode or Command Line Tools
2. Set **Project Format** in your project to **Xcode 8.3-compatible**

Possible solution:

1. Open XCode.app (Show Package Contents)
2. Find and open **version.plist**
3. Change ProductBuildVersion from **9C40b** to **9C40**
4. Set **Project Format** in your project to **Xcode 8.3-compatible**
5. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a deployment problem in Apple Servers. I tried after 3 hours and magically disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode -> Go to Organizer -> Under Archives, select the build and right click to Show in finder -> Select the Project and right click to -> Show Package Contents -> Double click on Info.plist and add a row. The key is  BuildMachineOSBuild and the Type is String and the Value is 16G29 (Value is based on your Mac OS Version. Please follow the below given link)

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201260   [.....Check the version number for your Mac OS version and set the value in the Info.plist](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201260)

For example if your Mac OS version is 10.12.6 then add this to your plist

```
<key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
<string>16G29</string>
```

You are ready to send your build to iTunes Connect

Answer (score 0):

I received this error having archived our app from the command line using `fastlane gym`.   When I archived the app manually using Xcode I did NOT receive the error.

I guess there's something wrong with the arguments/config I am passing to `fastlane gym`.  If I work out what this is I will report back.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload app to App Store through beta Version of Xcode. Make sure you're using stable version to push app to App Store

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add what is says at the bottom of the Using Apple Beta Software page (https://developer.apple.com/support/beta-software/)
IF you are using a BETA version of XCode and try to submit it will fail every time UNLESS you are on a GM_seed (Golden Master release, aka the release before the release to production)
Since I do not have enough "reputation" to comment @Chuck Smith. I created this. 
Hope this helps. 
*Today is 11/8/2019* and I downloaded and submitted my app with success.

Submitting Apps

***Apps that are created using beta versions of Xcode or that are built for beta versions of an OS will not be accepted on the App Store.*** Apps that you submit should be developed using the most up-to-date version of Xcode from the Mac App Store and should be built for publicly available versions of iOS, macOS, watchOS, and tvOS — ***except when GM seeds are available.*** When a GM Seed of Xcode becomes available, use it to develop your app for submission. When GM seeds of iOS, macOS, watchOS, or tvOS become available, build your app for these versions.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is what I did after going through the internet.

1. Download the latest Xcode from https://xcodereleases.com/ (You can download without signing in).
2. You might get an error "**Data is corrupted**" when you extract above-downloaded file ending with **.xip**
3. To solve this unzip it using **Archive Utility.app** rather than **The Unarchiver.app**

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while i was uploading for apple review using Xcode 11.2.

Fixes steps:
Apple decided to deprecate Xcode 11.2 on November 5th 2019. 
Xcode 11.2 has UITextView Building buggy code. So, Apple suggested to use Xcode 11.2.1 GM seed.

You can download from link https://developer.apple.com/download/

Message From Apple:
This update fixes a critical issue that could cause apps using UITextView to crash when run on previous versions of iOS, iPadOS, or tvOS. Please see the release notes

You can build and release app using Xcode 11.2.1 GM seed. Hoping this will help some people.

Answer (score 0):

**November 2019 with Xcode 12.1?**

2 days ago Apple released a 11.2.1 version which you can download/update from App Store. Fixing this problem as of today is as easy as installing/updating Xcode 12.2.1 from the official App Store.

Checked it on my app and was able to successfully deploy after this update, just make sure to upload the app build with the **new** Xcode (12.2.1), otherwise you'll see an error `Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported version of Xcode or SDK. If you plan to submit...`.

You should see again the green, positive confirmation :)

[image]

Comment: Confirming this error on Xcode 12 beta 4 (12A8179i).

Answer (score 0):

Before I am using **Xcode 12 beta version** and the reason is that only.

I have downloaded the **stable** version of **Xcode 12** and **IPA** got validated successfully.

You can download latest version from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the archive with the latest stable(not beta) version of Xcode.