# iOS app showing Invalid Binary Xcode 11 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, xcode11

I am uploading the app from Xcode 11 Beta6 and it is showing invalid binary

Error is like this:

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for App Store review for your app, "app" 2.40 (5821). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90111: Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a beta version of Xcode or SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the GM version of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11, tvOS 11, watchOS 4, or macOS 10.13 or later.
```

Can anyone help me out from this problem?

I have tried all this answers [ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323009/error-itms-90534-invalid-toolchain)

**UPDATE** :

Based on the answer and comment i have tried to run my app in xcode 10.2 now it is showing me error like this (it is because i have some fixed UI related to iOS13)

> The document "Main.storyboard" could not be opened. Failed to unarchive element named "collectionViewCellContentView".

[image]

Comment: APS built with Xcode 11 can be used for TestFlight but they cannot be submitted for review to be published in the App Store. You must use Xcode 10.2 to release apps at this time.

Comment: @Paulw11 check my updated question

Comment: If you have used Xcode 11 features then you either need to wait until Apple is accepting Xcode 11 builds (sometime next month probably) or open the project in Xcode 11, remove those features and then rebuild with Xcode 10.

Comment: @Paulw11 checkout my answer i have fixed the issue it was issue in collectionview in iOS13 content view is changed it to `collectionViewCellContentView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode beta version I have used collection view in once screen now when I open the project in XCode 10 version then it was showing the issue in collection view `"collectionViewCellContentView"` I have renamed it to `"view"`

**Xcode 11 Beta - UICollectionview**

```
<collectionViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="3lR-aq-iNR">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        </collectionViewCellContentView>
```

**Xcode 10.2**

```
<view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="3lR-aq-iNR">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        </view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a non-beta version of Xcode. You can use eg. Xcode 10.2

Comment: try to redo the collectionViewCellContentView using the old Xcode