# Could not find module 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' for target 'armv7-apple-ios';

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this crash at a few places through my app which seems to be triggered by IQKeyboardManagerSwift. I get this error in my AppDelegate.swift file on line 10 which is just 
`import IQKeyboardManagerSwift. It was all working fine before I updated to the latest version of Swift, howver all my dependencies are up to date. Including IQKeyboardManagerSwift. Has anyone seen a message like this before?

> Could not find module 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' for target
>   'armv7-apple-ios'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios

In the console I also get this message.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate
>   class named _UITextLayoutView because no class named _UITextLayoutView
>   was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in
>   from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)'

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug in Xcode 11.2

See:
[After upgrading to Xcode 11.2 from Xcode 11.1, app crashes due to _UITextLayoutView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657087/after-upgrading-to-xcode-11-2-from-xcode-11-1-app-crashes-due-to-uitextlayoutv)

You can either download an older Xcode version from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
or upgrade to the newly released 11.2.1 (I haven't tried that one yet)