# Xcode 12.3 iOS 14.3 simulators Yellow Dock / yellow translucent issues

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Today I downloaded the release of Xcode 12.3, and I went running the iOS 14.3 simulators and it seems like there is a graphic glitch that all translucent views are yellow, dock included.

I redownloaded iOS 14.2 and those seem fine. It just seems really odd. I've submitted feedback, but I was curious if anyone else has seen this?

I'm on [macOS v10.15.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) and am curious of if it's just Catalina or also [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur).

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Happening on Big Sur too.

Comment: Same here: Xcode 12.3, Big Sur, 15" 2018 MBP. Could you please mention your feedback identifier so that we can corroborate the issue to Apple?

Comment: This is only happening on my iPhone 12 Pro simulator. Just tested on iPhone 12 Mini, which works fine! :-)

Comment: Seen on Catalina 10.15.7 today as well for iPhone 11 iOS 14.3 simulator

Comment: @Pomme2Poule hi!, my fb is : FB8940468

Comment: Same problem here: Big Sur 11.1, Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33), iMac Retina 5K 27" 2019.

Comment: Could you check with simctl to see if the yellow shows up in a screenshot as well? Then can you use the OS screenshot feature to trigger an iOS screenshot into the camera roll and report it that shows the same yellow?

Comment: It is fixed in Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Comment: @user1046037 Is that confirmed? I wasn't seeing the bug so I can't check the fix. :)

Comment: I was experiencing it earlier and now it doesn’t happen for iOS simulator. I think the release note also mentions that it is fixed for iOS simulator

Answer (score 194):

**Xcode 12.4 RC has announced fix.**

> iOS simulated devices no longer display an incorrect yellow tint in translucent UI elements. Certain GPUs may continue to display the tint with some tvOS simulators. (71203015)

---

I think it is a bug related to the discrete GPU.

In addition, this bug causes the background of the on-screen keyboard to be almost RGB(0,0,0). Experienced on MBP 2017 with Catalina.

**Workaround I - Using integrated GPU**

1. In the simulator, set menu *File* → *GPU Selection* → *Prefer Integrated GPU* to work around this bug.
2. Restart the simulator.

This was tested on a MacBook Pro with Catalina and Big Sur. As comments suggest that it won't work on iMac.

**Workaround II - Reduce transparency**

In the simulated device (e.g. iPhone), *Settings* → *Accessibility* → *Display & Text Size* → turn on *Reduce Transparency*.

Notice that it can only reduce the previous 'solid' yellow to 'fairly light'.

I find this workaround, as the discrete GPU can be used, is more suitable for testing the UI logic than the previous solution.

This was tested on a MacBook Pro with Catalina. Might work on iMac.

Comment: This fixes the problem for every start of the simulator.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me (macOS 11.1, MacBook Pro 2016) but makes the simulator miserably slow when performing basic UI animations.

Comment: Restart your simulator after making this change to see the effects

Comment: This works on Catalina, just remember to restart the simulator. No need to unplug anything. Best

Comment: makes it super slow btw.

Comment: The workaround does not work for me. (Big Sur 11.1, Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33), iMac Retina 5K 27" 2019.)

Comment: This solution also works in the simulator within Xcode's SwiftUI view preview. However I had to restart Xcode to get it to notice the new GPU setting.

Comment: To be honest, I think the best "workaround", during development, is probably mentally ignore the 'transparent so yellow' and train the brain so that it's been treated as transparent. Happy debuging!

Comment: Reducing transparency helps a lot on my iMac but not completely. Does anyone know what the right fix is for the iMac?

Comment: Not working with eGPU + Big Sur + MBP '19

Comment: The first workaround worked for me. I'm using Catalina (10.15.7)

Comment: The "Workaround I - Using integrated GPU" worked with me (on Xcode 12.3, Big Sur 11.0.1, MBP2019), thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me either, on an 27" iMac 5K Late 2015 running Catalina 10.15.7.

I downloaded the older 14.2 simulator to use while this is still an issue, which works fine.

Comment: should be accepted answer. Don't forget to reload the simulator, guys

Comment: Thanks for reporting the Xcode 12.4 fix; have we confirmed that it really does fix it?

Comment: @matt confirm on mbp2017 with Catalina.

Comment: @zrfrank Yay! Glad to hear it

Comment: this works but the bug wasn't fixed in xcode 12.4 for me

Answer (score 15):

Are you using a MacBook Pro? I had the same bug.

I solved in the following ways.

- Step 1: Unplug all cables, including the charging cable
- Step 2: Restart the iOS simulator

Comment: This did work but the issue comes back on starting the Simulator next time when the power cable is connected.

Comment: In light of @zrfrank answer, I guess that unplugging the MacBook makes it switch to its integrated GPU so this can indeed work. It didn't work for me because I had "Prefer Discrete GPU" checked.

Comment: Works, as long as you don't plug the power back in and restart the simulator again. So I guess unplugging the power cable just make the simulator switch to integrated gpu, and back again to discrete, once the power is back.

Comment: I suggest you try the @zrfrank  "Workaround I - Using integrated GPU", it worked just fine on my MBP 2019 (Xcode 12.3, Big Sur 11.0.1) even if I then restart the Simulator again.

Answer (score 6):

Best way around it (what I've done), is to download the 14.2 Simulator pack from within Xcode.

1. Open Xcode->Preferences
2. Tap Components
3. Tap the 14.2 Simulator pack and Xcode is going to start installing it.

[image: xcode components]
It's a workaround till they fix that miserable error.

Comment: After trying the above mentioned workarounds, this one fixed the problem. For some reason, I previously had a "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (14.3) in the scheme selector, although just 14.1 and 14.2 simulators were installed. Therefore, this must be changed as well.

Comment: However, the SwiftUI previews are not fixed by that, still showing strange things...

Comment: And as every new Xcode there are hundreds of issues to fix before I can continue my work. Thanks Apple!!! BTW none of the mentioned workarounds fixed it...

Answer (score 5):

It is **Xcode 12.3** bug! you can see that sometimes in the code interface builder too:

[image: same]

It is not critical but If you really care about it, download and use [the previous Xcode from here](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_12.2/Xcode_12.2.xip)

**Nothe that** you can't build for iOS 14.3 if you choose to use Xcode 12.2.

## More description

Xcode always have unknown issues at the release point. Some of them are critical [like this with 54K views!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660634/5623035) and some are not like this issue with about 5K views in only 13 days.
My suggestion is to always have 2 Xcodes at the same time until you are sure about Xcode bugs!

Comment: I had Xcode 12.3 and Version 12.5 solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me as well, while I was charging my MacBook Pro 2016. I closed my Xcode, disconnected my charger from the Macbook and run it again. The problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to point out/confirm: Seems the issue is limited to the simulator. The issue does not persist when sideloading the project to iPhone.