# Navigation Bar default color is incorrect in Storyboard and Simulator

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, xcode-storyboard, xcode12

I have encountered a strange issue using Xcode 12.3

I created a brand new single view iOS app, selected the storyboard and embedded the ViewController in a NavigationController.  As soon as the NavigationController appears the NavigationBar changes to yellow.

If I run the app in the simulator it also displays as yellow.  If I run it on a physical device it behaves as expected and does not display as yellow.  If I change the bar tint from default to any other color it displays as expected (correctly) in storyboard, the simulator, and on a physical device.

It was not behaving this way on the previous version of Xcode.  Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Here is the screenshot before I embed it:

[image: Before NavigationController]

Here is the storyboard after the embed:

[image: After embed]

Here is a screenshot of the simulator.

[image: Running in the simulator]

Comment: So right after posting this I noticed that Translucent was checked in the Attributes Inspector.  Turning it off gets rid of the yellow.  Still not sure what is going on with this though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 12.3 iOS 14.3 simulators Yellow Dock / yellow translucent issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299337/xcode-12-3-ios-14-3-simulators-yellow-dock-yellow-translucent-issues)

Answer (score 0):

Choose the option from Simulator-> File-> GPU Selection-> PreferIntegratedGPU and restart the simulator[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqjzs.png)