# IOException occurred while uploading build to testflight

Tags: ios, testflight, xcode12

An exception has occurred: IOException occurred
ERROR ITMS-90534: “Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported SDK or version of Xcode. If you plan to submit this build to the App Store, make sure you are using the versions listed in https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf16aefe3b or later.”

The app was built using the xcode 12.0.1 which is the latest Appstore version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't submit apps to AppStore: ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323009/cant-submit-apps-to-appstore-error-itms-90534-invalid-toolchain)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error since you are using beta version of XCode, to avoid this error, use public version of XCode & this error will be resolved.

This problem occurs on Xcode 11.2 mostly. So, please update your Xcode by downloading it from Mac App Store.

Here is the link to download Xcode 11.2.1:-

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12